# Google Sheet Reverse VLOOKUP and Concatenate with Reference

Tags: google-sheets

I need help to solve this problem in my google sheets.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Ih4.png)

After I search, the closest solution is:

> =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTER(A4:A10,C4:C10=E3))

But the solution is not there.

Can you help me out to solve this?

[This is link to the sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GBmcjyr-YS_uGeNDajHGfnnnBrJS5uBUTfca531OC_o/edit?usp=sharing)
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In E4 try

```
=filter($A$4:$A&" "&$B$4:$B, $C$4:$C=E$3)
```

and fill to the right.
See if that helps?

Comment: Thank you! it works. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A4:A&" "&B4:B, C4:C}&"×", 
 "select max(Col1) 
  where not Col1 starts with ' ' 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×"))))
```

[image]

Comment: This function works too, but it adds additional header. Thank you too!

Comment: @Faro to remove the header you can do: `=QUERY(INDEX(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A4:A&" "&B4:B, C4:C}&"×", 
 "select max(Col1) 
  where not Col1 starts with ' ' 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×")))), "offset 1", 0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be helpful:

```
=JOIN(" and ", (UNIQUE(FILTER($A$4:$A$11,$C$4:$C$11=E3))))
```

You could fill the right columns with this script.

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) get correct values

[UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) return list without duplicates

[JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) concatenate strings in the list with separator(" and " in my example)